# An arabic phrase 'not doing something to a person's likings, deficient' equivalent?

Tags: phrase-requests

The phrase in arabic is 'مقصر في شيء', it literally means 'deficient in something'. So for example, if a wife said it about her husband, it would  mean that he's doing some of what is asked and expected of him, but not enough, or not to her liking. A friend can also say it to a friend, it may mean that he hasn't asked about his health, work or even life as often as usual; he is not caring as is expected of him.

It can also mean not helping, not being there, a lack of presence, a lack of doing what you should be doing towards someone/something.

A government or a company can also be a victim of this, towards their people and employees respectively.

It's a criticism, usually said out of love.

Comment: Hi @mahpack, please can you describe what you mean by your last sentence "It's a critique, usually said out of love".

Comment: What are you asking?  Whether there's an English equivalent?

Comment: @karasinsky, sorry I just edited it. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking @deadrat

Comment: @mahpack, thanks for the edit. I'm also a little unclear about "said out of love" though.

Comment: @karasinsky, what I mean is, that by lovingly chiding them, he doesn't intend to make it grow any bigger, he just wants to let them know, because he usually cares about them, it's usually meant like that. Sometimes it isn't.

Comment: *cutting corners* for your first paragraph-- it's what a person doing *slipshod* work is doing.   But it sounds like you're looking for an admonishment like, "you can do better than this."

Comment: If it's something that is said in order to point out a shortcoming and is intended to be helpful (or at least neutral) rather than hurtful or punitive, perhaps "constructive criticism" will *sometimes* fit, based on your examples and further explanation.

Comment: "Pick up the slack" might be useful here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the context correctly. Could you give a concrete example, give us the setting, the relationship of the people involved, what one person is doing, what the other person expects, and as much of what that person would say in English as you can. Something like: At home, husband cleans up a spill but leaves some behind and walks away; wife expects him to be more thorough; Wife says, "Aw honey, I have to say that's really ____. You missed all this part!" is what I think you're looking for, in which case I would suggest that *disappointing* is the word in the English.

Answer (score 1):

**fall short of** might encompass what you're after.

fall short of: fail to satisfy, as of expectations. ([thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fall+short+of))

*How was I supposed to know I was doing something wrong or [falling short of](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=nkzLMG08h9YC&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=%22short+OF+Her+expectations+as+a%22&source=bl&ots=8w2r0g-7R0&sig=cV5ywHTRNmLJVTnQ-6d7E1ooKy4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIiOr2nI6tyAIVBw8aCh0ekQc1#v=onepage&q=%22short%20OF%20Her%20expectations%20as%20a%22&f=false) her expectations as a friend if she didn't say a word?*

Answer (score 0):

**Stubborn** comes to mind.

> You're so **stubborn**, why won't you come to the zoo with us?!
>
> My wife is so **stubborn** because she refuses to finish her education.
>
> This child is so **stubborn**.  He will not eat his broccoli.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stubborn

Answer (score 0):

Inconsistent, Capricious, or Unreliable come to mind. But since you mentioned its done out of love, I think inconsistent would work work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

When it is said by the person who is not doing something enough as you expect, or not doing as s/he should be/want to, it usually means that I care about you and I'm aware that *I had not been [caring](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caring) enough* - **in an apologetic tone.**

However, when it is said by the person who expects the care but not getting it, it is more like *reproach* s/he would say: *You'd been [negligent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negligent)*

> **Caring**: painstaking or watchful attention
>
> **negligent**: failing to exercise the care expected of a reasonably
> prudent person in like circumstances

Answer (score 0):

The term "half-assed" is used in US English to suggest an work product that is inferior, lacking, or wanting in some quality or characteristic.

oxforddictionaries.com

verb

Do (something) with little effort or care:
"they half-assed the redesign"

adjective

Done with little effort or care:
"he did a half-ass job"

Comment: If you are looking for an expression, you could also use "phoning it in" to suggest a lack of effort or commitment.

Answer (score 0):

If I felt this way about someone close I might say they are **neglectful** or **neglecting** me. This implies that they have a responsibility to provide some sort of support, and are failing to do so, and it's often said of a parent or spouse who fails to provide proper support to their dependents.